# While using Measurement, I am unable to return a Double even though it is supposed to return a Double?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In an attempt to create a function using Swift's Measurements which returns a Double. I apparently am smol brained and can't figure out why, even though my function is calling to return a double, it is giving me an error of the following :
`Cannot convert return expression of type 'Measurement<UnitLength>' to return type 'Double'`

```swift
func convertImperialHeightToCM() -> Double {

        // User input of Feet, forcing unwrap will likely fuck this up...
   let convertFeetToCm = Measurement(value: userData!.userHeightFeet, unit: UnitLength.feet)
   let feetToCentimeters = convertFeetToCm.converted(to: UnitLength.centimeters)

        // User input of Inches, forcing upwrap will likely fuck this up...
   let convertInchesToCm = Measurement(value: userData!.userHeightInches, unit: UnitLength.inches)
   let inchesToCentimeters = convertInchesToCm.converted(to: UnitLength.centimeters)

        // Compute this shit and whip the numbers into one... 
   let addUpCentimeters = feetToCentimeters + inchesToCentimeters
        
   return addUpCentimeters
}
```

I am then calling this function later on in other functions as well (will likely make a single nested function but breaking them up to help with testability, plus I'm a noob.

Comment: `addUpCentimeters.value`?

Comment: `Measurement` does not "return" anything. It stores its value as a `Double`, and you can access it like New Dev suggested `addUpCentimeters.value` and return it, but as it stands, you're trying to return a `Measurement` object when your function declares a `Double`.

Comment: This whole function is a little suspect. Typically, you get the most benefit from  the `Measurement` by using it as the "common currency" type for all measurements across your system. You should only ever convert to a `Double` or other type like that "at the last possible moment", right at the boundary of your system (e.g. where you make a JSON payload for a web API call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that addUpCentimeters is a measurement unit, not a double. You therefore have two options, either you return that unit, or you call addUpCentimeters.value to get the actual double value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.value** to **feetToCentimeters** and **inchesToCentimeters** to get the Double value from **Measurement**.

```
func convertImperialHeightToCM() -> Double {

        // User input of Feet, forcing unwrap will likely fuck this up...
   let convertFeetToCm = Measurement(value: userData!.userHeightFeet, unit: UnitLength.feet)
   let feetToCentimeters = convertFeetToCm.converted(to: UnitLength.centimeters).value

        // User input of Inches, forcing upwrap will likely fuck this up...
   let convertInchesToCm = Measurement(value: userData!.userHeightInches, unit: UnitLength.inches)
   let inchesToCentimeters = convertInchesToCm.converted(to: UnitLength.centimeters).value

        // Compute this shit and whip the numbers into one... 
   let addUpCentimeters = feetToCentimeters + inchesToCentimeters
        
   return addUpCentimeters
}
```